# compiling portable version of ruby

Tags: ruby, compilation

I'm trying to compile a portable version of Ruby. Everything compiles, and works on the host system, but when I tar it up and send it to another server - it pukes:

```
/tmp/linux/ruby/bin/ruby: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.11' not found (required by                /tmp/linux/ruby/bin/ruby)
/tmp/linux/ruby/bin/ruby: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by   /tmp/linux/ruby/bin/ruby)
/tmp/linux/ruby/bin/ruby: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.6' not found (required by   /tmp/linux/ruby/bin/ruby)
```

Basically, the version of glibc I'm using is greater on the server I compiled it on. However, what I'm trying to do is statically link ruby on compile time. Is this possible? At compile time provide everything it will need?

Here are my configure options:

```
./configure --prefix=/data/linux/ruby \
--disable-install-doc \
--with-static-linked-ext \
--with-openssl-dir=/data/linux/openssl \
--with-zlib-dir=/data/linux/zlib
```

Everything compiles - but like I said does not work on other systems with different libraries.